# codename native Android application subclassing issues

Tags: java, codenameone

My codenameone application crashes anything I use this native code

```
package com.mycompany.interfaces;
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging;
public class InitialiseApp extends Application{

     private static Context context;

    public static Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }

     @Override
    public void onCreate() 

    {
        super.onCreate();

        context = getApplicationContext();

     try
        {
         FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this, new FirebaseOptions.Builder().
                    setApiKey("XXXXXXXXXXXXXX").
                    setApplicationId("XXXXXXXX").
                    setGcmSenderId("XXXXXXXXXX")
                    .build());

        FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteInstanceId();

        FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken("XXXXXXXXXX",FirebaseMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE);

        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("test");
        }
        catch(Exception c)
        {
            c.printStackTrace();
        }




    }
}
```

I declare the class in the android.xapplication_attr    android:name="com.mycompany.interfaces.InitialiseApp"

Need a assistance

Comment: please post log

Comment: As James said, this isn't a native interface. It's unclear how you are using this?

Comment: Hello Shai, the code is in the android native directory with its relevant libraries. i am trying to instantiate the FirebaseApp  as a singleton so it will be called once in the application cycle. I  extended the InitialiseApp  as an application class so it will be called once

Answer (score 0):

Are you putting this in the native interface stub or in the CN1 part of the code?

Also, I don’t think that’s how you get a context in CN1. Look in the developer guide and video tutorials for Native Interfaces. I also recall a series of blog posts about native interfaces that dive into writing the Android code. You’ll need to use something from the AndroidNativeUtil class like: AndroidNativeUtil.getActivity().

Comment: the code is in the android native directory with its relevant libraries. i am trying to instantiate the FirebaseApp as a singleton so it will be called once in the application cycle. I extended the InitialiseApp as an application class so it will be called once